# why am I getting Cannot resolve symbol 'someImpl' error in android studio?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I've been going back and forth with this for 2 days now and haven't been able to find a solution for it.

I'm trying to add an `AAR` file to my react-native project.

I added the AAR file by going to `File >> Project Structure >> JAR/AAR Dependency` and added the direct link to the AAR file which is in my libs folder.

I have this in my build.gradle(:app) :

```
implementation files('/Users/XXX/Desktop/projectName/android/libs/fileName.aar')
implementation(name:'fileName', ext:'aar')
implementation fileTree(dir: '/Users/XXX/Desktop/projectName/android/libs', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
```

However, when try to compile my app, the compile fails and Android studio complains with this error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'someImpl'
```

This is the code that its complaining about:

```
  public void ListPrinters(Callback cb){
         someImpl printerDiscovery = new someImpl(this.context);


    }
```

what am I doing wrong? and why the studio giving me that error?

Comment: @Thanhal, not sure what I should be looking at there since that question is not related to my question!

Comment: @Thanhal, no the issue is related to the aar file and its class.

Comment: Okay sorry. Not have much knowledge about that